# Resizing UISearchBar in UINavigation Bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uisearchbar

I have added UISearchBar to UINavigationBar and this works really well, Except the left padding of UISerachBar here.
On Debug I came to know that here back button frame is too large that's why UINavigation bar title view shifted from left too much.
How to deal with that?

I want to achieve something like twitter app where the spacing between back button and search bar is not much.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Are you adding the search bar as a titleView or the rightView?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom back button in your navigation bar to override the default back button (in this case the left button):

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my-back-button-image.png"]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 43, 30);

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageView];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
```

The space between left button and search controller decreases.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier by **Michele Broggi** you can try that.

**Else**

You can also set the search Bar in place of navigation Title view so that it would be centre aligned to the screen (If you want that design)